# Why is this equal to 1?

Tags: products

Why is

$$ \prod_{i=4}^0 (4i -1) = 1  $$

At least according to: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?=prod_{i%3D4}^0+%284*i+-+1%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod_%7Bi=4%7D%5E0%20%284%2ai%20-%201%29)
It is rather unintuitive, why would the product even be defined? One could however interpret it as letting i decrease from 4 to 0. But that clearly is not the case. So what's going on?

Answer (score 7):

An empty product, by definition, is equal to $1$. An empty sum is defined as $0$.

You can think of it as a generalization of the idea that $a^0=1$ and $0!=1$.

More generally, if you have a finite set, $X$, and a function $f:X\to \mathbb R$, then for any subset $A\subset X$, you can define:

$$\prod_{x\in A} f(x)$$

this product has the property that if $A,B\subset X$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ then $$\prod_{x\in A\cup B} f(x) = \left(\prod_{x\in A} f(x)\right)\left(\prod_{x\in B} f(x)\right)$$

For this to be defined for *all* subsets of $A$, we have to define it for $A=\emptyset$. The only value for $\prod_{x\in \emptyset} f(x)$ that keeps the above property is $1$.

Comment: Proof: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E4+%284*i-1%29] - note link doesn't work, copy/paste into browser

Comment: D@gt6989b Not proof. That's just evidence. As far as anybody knows, WolframAlpha is wrong - indeed, the above question is questioning WA...

Comment: All right great it wasn't a WolframAlpha fluke thankfully!

Comment: I don't think "by definition" is right.  It's a demonstable result; not a definition.

Comment: Well, as you note in a comment below, there is a fluke in WA in that it evaluates the corresponding sum as non-zero, which is inconsistent.

Comment: How do you define $\prod_{x\in A} f(x)$ for $A$ finite, then @MichaelHardy?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Just in the obvious way.

Comment: Sorry, but "the obvious way" still requires a definition. What is the definition?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Indeed, your answer shows that it's a demonstrable result and not just a definition.

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, my argument shows why you'd want it, not why it is true. You still need to prove that $\prod_{x\in A}$ *can* be defined with this union property. I'm just saying we'd like this property, not that we can prove it without definition. (It can't be defined in rings with non-commutative products, for example.)

Comment: . . . but not with non-associative products.  I may address this topic at length elsewhere at some point.

Comment: Well, not if there is no identity in the ring. Define it for $f:X\to 2\mathbb Z$. @MichaelHardy The point is, we can certainly say that *if* $\prod_{x\in A}$ can be defined for all $A\subseteq X$ and $f$ with the above property, *then* $\prod_{x\in \emptyset} f(x)=1$. But it can't always be defined with this property, and the easiest way to define $\prod$ is inductively, starting with the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

WA probably considers this product (where the upper bound is less than the lower bound) to be empty. And the empty product is 1 by definition (just like the empty sum is zero). So it's not really a math question, more like a Mathematica question.

Comment: This one is not empty: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_{i%3D4}^0+%284*i+-+1%29
How do we interpret that result?

Comment: That looks like a bug in WA. Or at the very least, an inconsistency. @infinityreward2

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a product in terms of $i$ from $4$ to $0$. Since $4\leq0$ is false, the set of $i$ such that $4\leq i\leq0$ is empty, and so this is an empty product. The empty product is defined to be $1$.

What you likely wanted was the following
$$\prod_{i=0}^{4}\left(4i-1\right).$$
[Putting this into Wolfram Alpha gives -3465.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod_%7Bi=0%7D%5E4%20%284%2ai%20-%201%29)

As far as I am aware, the standard way to interpret your product notation is that it would be the empty product, as Wolfram Alpha seems to interpret it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I intentionelly wanted to sum from i = 4 to i = 0 in order to observe the results.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram is probably contruing $\displaystyle\prod_{i=4}^0$ as the product over all values of $i$ that are $\ge4$ and simultaneously $\le0$.  There are none, so you are multiplying no numbers at all.

Multiplying by no numbers at all is the same as multiplying by $1$.